# How do encode an URL with PHP to show correctly in email clients

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, urlencode

I am sending a text mail with PHPMailer, which contains an URL:

http://www.sdsdfdsf.com/?mail=mike@hotmail.com

At some email clients, the URL is not converted correctly to a Link. Sometimes the URL stops at the @-Symbol.

How to encode the parameters of an URL with PHP, that all email clients show the URL correctly?

Comment: check `urlencode` method - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: it´s also necesarry to use urlDecode, when my backend gets the "mail"-paramteter?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the full  use the email to

h̶t̶t̶p̶:̶/̶/̶w̶w̶w̶.̶s̶d̶s̶d̶f̶d̶s̶f̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶?̶m̶a̶i̶l̶=̶m̶i̶k̶e̶@̶h̶o̶t̶m̶a̶i̶l̶.̶c̶o̶m̶ ̶

```
<a href="mike@hotmail.com">Email Me</a>
```

[Mail to Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto)